# Angular material list item does not work with async pipe that contains delay()

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-nav-list` that looks like this:

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let draft of drafts$() | async">
        <ng-container *ngIf="getImageUrl$(draft) | async as imageUrl">
            <img matListAvatar [src]="imageUrl">
        </ng-container>
        <h1 matLine>{{draft.name}}</h1>
        <p matLine>{{draft.description}}</p>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Why `<img matListAvatar [src]="imageUrl">` will not display the image when the `getImageUrl$(draft)` contains a `pipe(delay())`? I am using delay to simulate actual async service call.

You can try the stackblitz [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-async-pipe-delay?file=app/app.component.ts). Tweak the demo to see expected behavior without `delay()`.

Is this an `async pipe` or `mat-list-item` behavior/bug or a problem with my code?

Comment: I think this has something to do with change detection.
When you add a `tap(console.log)` to your `Observable`, you will see an infinite amount of log statements meaning that `getImageUrl$(draft)` gets recalled as soon as the `Observable` completes (i. e. after the delay).

Comment: I got it to work by running it outside of the NgZone and then triggering change detection manually. There must be a better solution but maybe this helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-async-pipe-delay-xokvdk?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I wanted to use async pipe because code looks clean but for this scenario it will not be so clean (especially moving into NgZone magic stuff hehe). i will switch back to non-async pipe style for this case. Appreciate your help & findings. :-)